# comparing volatilities of 2 different commodities when no delta is provided

Tags: volatility, delta, spread, commodity

If I wanted to compare the relative volatilities of options on 2 different commodities, but the deltas are not provided, is it sufficient to compare by the % each commodities strike is in or out of the money?

For example: Compare a 1-dollar out of the money NG put to a 15-dollar out of the money power put when both strikes are 40% of their respective futures prices

Comment: I would say no, because each commodity has different IV and RV. I would compare on a standard-deviation OTM basis rather than %moneyness.

Comment: Do you have prices for these options? If so then yes you can compute implied vols for both. If you just have a option but no context (price or delta) then no there's nothing to imply.